# Normalizing DateTime of MySQL Data

Tags: mysql, normalization

I am working on a database that aggregates financials data observations (consider the currency pair USDCAD as an example).

The financial data comes in as observations. I don't set the date and time for the observations as it is determined by the data provider.

My table looks like this:
`CREATE TABLE observations (symbol varchar(32) not null, datetime datetime not null, value decimal(20, 10) not null);`

The problem arises when I need to get the value of the series at a time when there was no specific observation. For example, I might want to reprice a certain product we are selling in Canadian Dollars at 10:30:15am.

However, it is possible that I will not have a USDCAD observation for 10:30:15am exactly. This will require me to do a weighted average to get to the observation at that exact time.

This is slightly cumbersome but possible. The bigger issue is this - if I have a table containing the US Dollar prices of our product every second, and I want to reprice every product price observation (every second) in USDCAD (where there are randomly timed observations), I can't think of a way to do this without crazy sub-queries.

What is my best option here? Is it better to calculate an every second observation for the USDCAD series too when values are inserted?

Comment: How about using a time range in where condition using mysql TIME(your column)

Comment: hey - not sure exactly how that solves the problem. how can I achieve weighted averages with TIME(column)?

Comment: What have you tries so far? if you have written any query please put it up so we can see how we can solve it

Comment: I don't really have a written query.. I was kind of hoping for input..

Comment: Do you have any sample data?? please put it up

Comment: Also see [Is It Needed to Normalize of Date Columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/101550/141074) on DBA.SE.

Answer (score 3):

1. Obtain weighted average observation at `@time` by applying [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation):

   ```
   SELECT p0.y + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@time)-p0.x) * (p1.y-p0.y) / (p1.x-p0.x)
   FROM
     (
       SELECT   `value`                     AS y
         ,       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) AS x
       FROM     `observations`
       WHERE    `datetime` <= @time
       ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
       LIMIT    1
     ) p0,
     (
       SELECT   `value`                     AS y
         ,       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) AS x
       FROM     `observations`
       WHERE    `datetime` >= @time
       ORDER BY `datetime` ASC
       LIMIT    1
     ) p1;
   ```
2. Create a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/views.html) of your products with CAD prices using the latest exchange rate:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW `productsCAD` AS
     SELECT `products`.*
       ,    `products`.`price` * `exchange`.`value` AS `priceCAD`
     FROM   `products`
       , (
         SELECT   `value`
         FROM     `observations`
         ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
         LIMIT    1
       ) AS `exchange`;
   ```

---

**UPDATE**

To obtain interpolated prices for multiple predefined times (assumed to be stored as `DATETIME` values in a column named `time` within a table named `times`), you need to use a subquery to first obtain the time of the immediately preceding and immediately following observations then join those with the observations table again to get the corresponding values:

```
SELECT time, p0.y + IFNULL((unixtime-p0.x) * (p1.y-p0.y) / (p1.x-p0.x), 0) AS value
FROM
  (
    SELECT
          time,
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`)               AS `unixtime`,
      MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`before`.`datetime`)) AS `prevTime`,
      MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `after`.`datetime`)) AS `nextTime`
    FROM
      `times`
      JOIN (SELECT `datetime` FROM `observations`)
        AS `before` ON (`before`.`datetime` <= `time`)
      JOIN (SELECT `datetime` FROM `observations`)
        AS `after`  ON ( `after`.`datetime` >= `time`)
    GROUP BY `time`
  ) AS `matches`
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) AS x,
      `value`                    AS y
    FROM `observations`
  ) AS p0 ON (p0.x = `matches`.`prevTime`)
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) AS x,
      `value`                    AS y
    FROM `observations`
  ) AS p1 ON (p1.x = `matches`.`nextTime`);
```

If you want to specify the desired times in the query (rather than using the predefined table `times`), replace the reference to `times` with a subquery that builds such a table dynamically using `UNION`:

```
SELECT time, p0.y + IFNULL((unixtime-p0.x) * (p1.y-p0.y) / (p1.x-p0.x), 0) AS value
FROM
  (
    SELECT
          time,
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`)               AS `unixtime`,
      MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`before`.`datetime`)) AS `prevTime`,
      MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `after`.`datetime`)) AS `nextTime`
    FROM
      (
                  SELECT '2012-05-02 19:20:00' AS `time`
        UNION ALL SELECT '2012-05-02 19:20:05'
        UNION ALL SELECT '2012-05-02 19:20:10'
        UNION ALL SELECT '2012-05-02 19:20:15'
        -- etc.
      ) AS `times`
      JOIN (SELECT `datetime` FROM `observations`)
        AS `before` ON (`before`.`datetime` <= `time`)
      JOIN (SELECT `datetime` FROM `observations`)
        AS `after`  ON ( `after`.`datetime` >= `time`)
    GROUP BY `time`
  ) AS `matches`
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) AS x,
      `value`                    AS y
    FROM `observations`
  ) AS p0 ON (p0.x = `matches`.`prevTime`)
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) AS x,
      `value`                    AS y
    FROM `observations`
  ) AS p1 ON (p1.x = `matches`.`nextTime`);
```

Comment: thank you so much. I really like 1), which is perfectly clear and very helpful! the only addition is that I discovered today that I need to do linear interpolation of the data regardless of the repricing thing. for example, lets say I have randomly dispersed observations at 1:04, 1:12, 1:17, 1:21 and 1:27 - I need to display the data as having observations of 1:00, 1:05, 1:10, 1:15, 1:20, 1:25, 1:30, and the respective data interpolated. your query does exactly this, but for a single value. is there a way to do this for multiple values in one query? thanks again.

Comment: thank you again! your query works very nicely. there is only one thing that I can't figure out, and its due to the fact that I simplified my question a bit. in my observations table, I have a column named series_id. this indicates which series the observation belongs to, and the system has many observations for different series all in this table. I need to perform the above on one series only, so I tried adding AND series_id = ID in all the ON clauses of the JOINs, but the query just runs forever and never returns.. I have 30,000 observations in the table currently. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: actually - the query does work, only the query takes 10 minutes to complete!! what is going on?

Comment: @user1094786: Do you have an index on `series_id`?

Comment: @user1094786: And it's that way around, with `series_id` in the leftmost column?  If so, I presume you also have another separate index with `datetime` in the leftmost column?

Comment: I do - here is my index definition: PRIMARY KEY (`series_id`, `datetime`). I then also added KEY (`datetime`) (which I'm not sure why - when am I looking up dates without a series_id?) but everything is still just as slow (it takes many minutes for the query to run)

Comment: @user1094786: You may need to rework the query to find the before/after observations with user variables instead of joins... I'll have a think about how that can be done.